# MATLAB: update surface plot and change location of line objects in while loop

Tags: matlab, plot, surface

So I am encountering a couple errors and am not sure where they're coming from. I won't post the whole code, but I will do my best to explain (fear I will be accused of plagiarism).

The assignment is to create a window with two plots: a surface plot and a contour plot. The surface plot represents elevation of a portion of the map represented by the contour plot. The portion is indicated by a blue box on the contour plot. I've successfully plotted the surface and contour plots and have identified the first area with a blue box. However, now I need to implement a menu system wherein the user enters 1, 2, 3, or 4 to move the box north, south, east or west.

Here is how I instantiated the plots:

```
fig = figure(1);
[xGrid, yGrid] = meshgrid(xMeters(xStart:xEnd), yMeters(yStart:yEnd));

%surface plot
elevationBox = ELEV(xStart:xEnd, yStart:yEnd);
surface = subplot(2, 1, 1);
surf(xGrid, yGrid, elevationBox);
axis([0 max(xGrid(:)) 0 max(yGrid(:)) min(elevationBox(:)) max(elevationBox(:))]);
axis tight;

%contour plot
elevation = ELEV;
[xMap, yMap] = meshgrid(xMeters(1:335), yMeters(1:230));
map = subplot(2, 1, 2); contour(xMap, yMap, elevation);
axis([0 max(xMeters(:)) 0 max(yMeters(:))]);
axis fill;
set(fig, 'Position', [500 100 600 700]);

right = line(xRight, xLeft);
left = line(xLeft, yLeft);
top = line(xTop, yTop);
bottom = line(xBottom, yBottom);
```

So all that works fine. Obviously I didn't include the parts where I defined the data and everything. After this comes a switch statement that changes the values of xLeft, yLeft, etc as well as xStart, xEnd etc.

Here is my attempt to update the plots:

```
[xGrid, yGrid] = meshgrid(xMeters(xStart:xEnd), yMeters(yStart:yEnd));
elevationBox = ELEV(xStart:xEnd, yStart:yEnd);
subplot(2, 1, 1)
    set(surface, 'XData', xGrid, 'YData', yGrid, 'ZData', elevationBox);

drawnow;
```

I can choose an option and there is no error, but the plot doesn't update and when I quit the program I get this error:

> Error using matlab.graphics.axis.Axes/set
>
> There is no XData property on the Axes class.
>
> Error in A9 (line 129)
>
> set(surface, 'XData', xGrid);

The setting is inside the while loop but outside the switch statement. I also had a few lines using set on the line objects but those weren't working either so I thought I'd focus here first. I'm figuring whatever I'm doing wrong applies to both object types but if not let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than grab a handle to the axis (which you call `surface`), you want the data object. So grab a handle at `surf_h = surf(...);`.

A little example:

```
% Generate a random surface grid
n = 10;
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:n, 1:n);
z = rand(n);

% Plot
fig_h = figure(1);
axis_h = subplot(2, 1, 1);
surf_h = surf(x,y,z);

% Modify XData
set(surf_h, 'XData', -x);
drawnow;
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought maybe that was the problem- "subplot" is its own object, then? I was considering it like... I don't know, just some kind of indicator, I guess I didn't think about it. Thanks, I'll give that a try!

Comment: Yep. You can find out what type of object it is using `get(handle, 'Type')`, and list all of its properties using `get(handle)`.